# Joomla 3 custom media queries style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, joomla3.0

I have a problem in Joomla 3 with custom media queries styles in a custom template. I`ve written custom css styles under different media queries but those are simply ignored. Custom style is active but I cannot overwrite some of those styles using medias queries. Queries  are correctly written (I don't have errors like syntax problem or false written queries, etc...) I've checked them all a few times over but I cannot find a problem. Any ideas?

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.
AB

Comment: Need to see your code, otherwise it would be tough to answer. I'm not a downvoter. Can you inspect your elements and see if your custom queries are actually being implemented?

Comment: Hi, yes they are implemented. This is my code:
/* Default */
.navigation ul li {
    width: 15%;
}
/* Large desktop */
(at)media (min-width: 1200px) {
.navigation ul li {
    width: 16.58%;
}
}
     
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
(at)media (max-width: 979px) {
  .navigation ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
}